# How to put 'perl -pne' functionality in a perl script

Tags: perl

So at the command line I can conveniently do something like this:

```
perl -pne 's/from/to/' in > out
```

And if I need to repeat this and/or I have several other `perl -pne` transformations, I can put them in, say, a `.bat` file in Windows. That's a rather roundabout way of doing it, of course. I should just write one `perl` script that has all those regex transformations.

So how do you write it? If I have a shell script containing these lines:

```
perl -pne 's/from1/to1/' in > temp
perl -pne 's/from2/to2/' -i temp
perl -pne 's/from3/to3/' -i temp
perl -pne 's/from4/to4/' -i temp
perl -pne 's/from5/to5/' temp > out
```

How can I just put these all into one `perl` script?

Comment: I think the `-i` flag overwrites the input file with the output, but I'm not sure. At least that's my intent anyway.

Comment: Small note: -p overrides -n so you don't need both. It's not much but I think the less arguments to a command the better. And yes, -i edits a file in place, see perlrun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-e` accepts arbitrary complex program. So just join your substitution operations.

```
perl -pe 's/from1/to1/; s/from2/to2/; s/from3/to3/; s/from4/to4/; s/from5/to5/' in > out
```

If you really want a Perl program that handles input and looping explicitely, deparse the one-liner to see the generated code and work from here.

```
> perl -MO=Deparse -pe 's/from1/to1/; s/from2/to2/; s/from3/to3/; s/from4/to4/; s/from5/to5/'
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/from1/to1/;
    s/from2/to2/;
    s/from3/to3/;
    s/from4/to4/;
    s/from5/to5/;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Awesome idea.  I do a good bit of Perl, and I frequently end up with a one-liner that grows to the point where it needs to be converted to a real script.  I can't believe I never thought to use Deparse as a shortcut to ease some of the longer one-liners.

Answer (score 6):

Related answer to the question you didn't *quite* ask: the [perl special variable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlvar) `$^I`, used together with `@ARGV`, gives the in-place editing behavior of `-i`. As with the -p option, Deparse will show the generated code:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -pi.bak -le 's/foo/bar/'
BEGIN { $^I = ".bak"; }
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    s/foo/bar/;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
```